# How to select feature first and then start the zoom animation

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to select a feature first and then start the zoom animation but openlayers (v6) first start the zoom animation and when it's done the feature gets selected, what's going on here?

Here is my code:

```
function zoom(){
    selectSingleClick.getFeatures().push(featToZoom);

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
    vectorSource.addFeature(featToZoom);

    map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), {
            duration: 5000
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found working solution by using `setTimeout` for zoom, but I didn't try to find reasons why it works. OpenLayers is a bit too complicated for my taste.

```
function zoom() {
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
  vectorSource.addFeature(featToZoom);

  map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), {
    duration: 5000
  });
}

function selectAndZoom(){
  selectSingleClick.getFeatures().push(featToZoom);
  setTimeout(zoom, 50);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much again TomazicM. I had some initial difficulties but I feel more and more comfortable with OL.

Comment: I will try it eventually, but at the moment, while learning GIS essentials, I'll stick to Leaflet.

Answer (score 2):

When you push a feature as following:

```
selectSingleClick.getFeatures().push(featToZoom);
```

OpenLayers generates internal event `CollectionEventType.ADD` ([link to source code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v6.1.1/src/ol/interaction/Select.js#L256)) and then highlights the feature. But, handler of event `CollectionEventType.ADD` doesn't run immediately. JavaScript engine has a single thread, forcing asynchronous events to queue waiting for execution (see [How JavaScript Timers Work](https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) by John Resig). But `map.getView().fit` run here immediately.

If we add `setTimeout()` then we move our `map.getView().fit` in the end of the queue. Then highlighting will be first, but zooming will be second:

```
function fitByFeature(feature){
    map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry().getExtent(), {
        duration: 5000
    });
}

function selectFeatureAndFit(feature) {
    selectSingleClick.getFeatures().push(feature);

    setTimeout(function () {
        fitByFeature(feature);
    });
}

// Get my feature from layer
var feature = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0];
selectFeatureAndFit(feature);
```

In addition, instead using a temporary `ol.source.Vector`:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
vectorSource.addFeature(featToZoom);
vectorSource.getExtent()
```

you could try to get an extent more easily:

```
feature.getGeometry().getExtent()
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ol-select-v1fp5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).